# Multiclass classification with Google AutoML Tables

Tags: classification, google-cloud-ml, multiclass-classification, google-cloud-automl, automl

I am using Google autoML tables for a multiclass classification problem where the number of classes is 110. For some reasons, the learned model only predicts probabilities for 40 classes and I don't understand why. These classes being the most frequent in the training set. Any help?

Thank you!

Yassine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you reported this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/162483435) as well.

Quoting the response given there:

> It seems that the service is only returning the top results instead of the results for all the available classes. The AutoML Tables Engineering team is aware of this behavior and currently working on a fix.

So, for those interested, the suggestion is to subscribe to the [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/162483435) to receive a notification whenever there's an update on the issue.